# Creating Null Modem Connection between two C64s?

Tags: commodore-64, modem

Trying to establish a null modem connection between 2 C64s using 1 Commodore 1660 300 Baud modem and 1 Commodore 1670 1200 Baud modem.

Does anybody have detailed instructions on how to configure the modems for text exchange and file exchange?

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with the Commodore 1630 modem.  Is that a typo?  I've heard of the 1600 VICmodem, the 1650 Automodem and the 1670 1200baud modem.

Also, a null modem connection is used when you have no modems.  You have 2 modems, so a null modem connection isn't what you want.  I think you may want a PBX that lets you create 2 internal 'extensions', then dial one extension from the other.  There is open-source PBX software available out there (e.g. Asterisk) so this does not need to be a terribly expensive option.

Comment: Or, possibly, to network the machines directly via their serial ports?

Comment: You may need a [line voltage inducer](http://www.dreamcastlive.net/shop.html) or telephone line simulator to get them to dial and talk to each other. Or try this [DIY RS-232 interface](http://biosrhythm.com/?p=1136) project that will give you a 2400 baud connection without the modems.

Comment: Yes, 1630 was a typo, meant 1660.

Comment: Is there a way to get the modems to connect directly to each other? One dialing the other with a telephone cable between them?

Comment: Generally speaking, you have to present a modem with a dialling tone or at least an *off-hook* signal, before it will dial.  Just wiring a telephone cable between them isn't enough and is not a null modem..  It would be a lot easier connecting the two computers together directly via RS232 - that is a null modem.

Comment: As mentioned above, this isn't a null modem setup at all. Maybe you could edit the question to include some more details on what you want to accomplish or simulate.

Comment: If the OP really wants to connect two modems together (not using an RS232 null modem) then a certain amount of phone line simulation is required to get things working.  I don't have time to write this up properly, but there is a nice walkthu here: http://jagshouse.com/modem.html

Comment: @Tommy, the C64 doesn't have an RS-323 port; the Commodore Serial Bus (a serial derivative of the parallel IEEE-488) doesn't look suitable for null-modem operation.  It looks like direct connection between two C64s will take a fair bit of hardware no matter what.

Comment: I'm quite certain I was able to get two modems to connect with only an extension cable between them back in the mid-90's but I don't have the equipment to try and confirm it now. I believe I used a command (possibly ATA) on one modem to cause it to generate the answer tone, and either ATO or ATDT (and perhaps a digit) to get the other modem to connect. Is my memory merely foggy or is this setup impossible?

Comment: @Mark I don't see why Commodore's serial bus is inadequate for connecting two computers, especially given that for many Commodore users that's exactly what it did: the 6502 and 6526 in the C64 communicated with the 6522 and 6502 in the 1541, where that 6502 used its ROM, RAM and drive mechanics to read and then serialise files for transmission. EDIT: I'm completely right. Assuming you speak German or can use Google Translate, see http://www.webnet.at/c64/serielles_netzwerk.htm

Comment: @Tommy, RS-232 is designed for DTE-to-DCE communication; swapping wire pairs in a null-modem cable makes each computer think *it* is the DTE and the other is the DCE.  This only works because the link is capable of full-duplex communication, with dedicated input and output lines.  Commodore Bus is designed for host-to-device communication.  It's half-duplex, with all lines being both input and output.  Any sort of "null modem" cable would leave both computers fighting over which one is the host and which is the device.  The fact that many C64 peripherals used 65xx CPUs is entirely irrelevant.

Comment: @Mark you're discussing a software problem, not a hardware problem. An ethernet-style probabilistic pausing approach would resolve that. Or just download the disk image from the page I previously linked to — it provides a 1–6 machine local area network for C64s using the serial bus. Proven and working.

Answer (score 9):

"Null modem cable" may not quite be a misnomer but is potentially misleading: it is a cable that connects two computers via their serial ports *without modems*. It's not a null cable for modems, it's the null example of one of those cables you use to connect a computer to a modem.

So if you want to make it look like there's a phone network between two modems that are really directly wired, you're not asking about null modem cables.

If you just want to network two C64s then the easiest thing is directly to connect them via their serial ports. That's not technically the same thing as the normal usage of the term "null modem cable" because that term is usually associated with full-duplex RS-232-style connections, whereas this will be half duplex but half duplex is no barrier whatsoever to networking. Ethernet is also half duplex.

[This page](http://www.webnet.at/c64/serielles_netzwerk.htm) contains a [German] write-up of networking via the Commodore serial bus, including [the necessary software](http://www.webnet.at/c64/serial.zip). Obviously you can use Google to read [a translated-to-English version](https://translate.google.com/translate?sl=auto&tl=en&js=y&prev=_t&hl=en&ie=UTF-8&u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.webnet.at%2Fc64%2Fserielles_netzwerk.htm&edit-text=&act=url).

Although the software is customised, the cable you'll need isn't. Any standard Commodore serial cable will do — impedance is sufficient that the author had no issues even with five C64s and a total cable length of 25 metres. So if you have a 1541 then just use the cable from that.

Comment: Data transfer rates could be improved enormously by wiring up many of the pins in the user ports.  If one was really careful, one could probably use a ribbon cable and a pair of IDC connectors if one was careful to cut all of the wires one didn't need and plug things in the right way, but mistakes could blow things up.

Answer (score 3):

I know this is anecdotal, but here is my personal testimony:

I built many circuits interfacing with the User Port in my teens (mostly digital control circuits using the data lines), and I'm pretty sure I interfaced my 128 and 64 together by directly wiring the two user port's TX/RX TTL lines together in a crossover fashion(along with ground, of course), but it has been a long time, so I may be remembering incorrectly.

I do, however, specifically remember connecting two 300 baud modems to each other on many occasions, using a simple RJ-11 jumper cable.  I would simply send the off-hook AT command to each modem (and I think another set of commands to initiate handshaking), and the computers were able to communicate...

Comment: Back in the '90s I used the modem-to-modem technique to transfer some text files between my C=64 and my PC as well.